# PHP/Mysql category making

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite newbie in programming and my English isn't very good, but I will try to explain my problem. It's been a time, while I'm been trying to find out how to make, that what I want. **I don't need You to write code to my, I just want to know where to start, what to learn and where to look for info.**

I will show simple example for that what I want to build.

Some simple example in Diagram photo(Backend System):
[image: First Image]

I want to make, That Color and etc. Can be added from Admin Control Panel
[image: Admin Panel]

Simple view of Adding things
[image: Adding Pages]

This is User Input, where Users can input thei "Cars" in DataBase (As topics)
[image: User Input]

On paper it looks quite simple, but I can't figure out where I need to start. How to make database like that? And how to make it all work? I know basics, how to input data in database and view it, but can't logic imagine how to make complex databases. I would be very happy, for any advices, suggestions, tutorials. Thanks anyone, who want to help! With Regrets, Crelix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should read some tutorials. For example this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/

I can give you some hints where to look for things:

Mostly it depends whether you want to do it in "plain" PHP + MySQL, or use some frameworks.

For example, using [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) you can create database with 1 command (see: [Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)). But for small learning project it will be an overkill. Of course learning Symfony framework will be an incomparable asset.

If you want just PHP, then you have to go with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You should get familiar with [PHP Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Regarding SQL:

- you can create all tables with [CREATE TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)
- to make reference to some other table you have to use [FOREIGN KEY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) constraint
- you can use tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to help you with the process

You probably want it to look somehow (other than black text on white page). There are many front-end frameworks, but you can start with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), i think it's easy to comprehend

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know basics. Like tables, classes, etc. I just can't logical imagine how to make it all how I want. I had been learning java for 6 months, and now trying to get in touch with pdo.

Comment: It's hard to explain it without writing a book :) Please see some tutorials, they should point you in the right direction. After you write some code (create base classes, setup mysql connection in php etc...) by yourself, we will help you with pleasure to fix things that are not working.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want a sample database and table structure.

For your project I would have one database we could call it vehicles.

I would then have a table called `cars`.

Each car would have a structure like this:

```
ID | color | country| region | ..... and so on
```

Each of these fields would be numeric, you would join the to other tables.

So you would have a `colors` table like this

```
ID | description
```

Lets say the color ID 1 has description red. If you wanted to find all red cars you would do

```
SELECT * FROM cars where color = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM cars INNER JOIN colors on cars.color = colors.ID
```

Each table would be pretty similar after this. Just an ID that you join on.

The reason you don't just store red in the car table is to save space in your database and also increase the speed.

I hope this helps you, I'm happy to explain further.

Comment: Thanks for Answering. My Idea is like example (engines) aren't defined in any code. But I can add they in ACP and later use where else I need. Not Only in Cars, or Motorbikes. And can add in pages where i need them. For example in sellcar.php I want to show (Engines) as list. Hope you understood? If no, I will try to explain.